# Here API returns the same travelTime for different departure time values

Tags: here-api

Calculate Matrix returns the same result for travelTime regardless of the value I specify for departure.

Here's the request:

```
https://matrix.route.api.here.com
/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json
?app_id={}
&app_code={}
&start0=42.697670,23.321766
&destination0=42.644611,23.410811
&destination1=42.674945,23.308694
&destination2=42.698543,23.308721
&destination3=42.668093,23.367410
&destination4=42.646305,23.367816
&destination5=42.629910,23.374102
&destination6=42.660108,23.382269
&destination7=42.136030,24.742189
&destination8=42.504910,27.462307
&destination9=42.606166,23.036060
&mode=fastest;car;
&traffic:enabled
&summaryAttributes=tt,di
&departure=2019-07-15T22:00:00
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please tell about the second departure time you are trying because we tried now for the second departure as 2019-07-15T23:00:00 and 2019-07-16T21:00:00. It is giving me different travel time with different values.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I didn't set "traffic" to "enabled".

The right way to do it is:

```
&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled;
```

as opposed to:

```
&mode=fastest;car;
&traffic:enabled
```